# AngularJS and UI sortable - no method 'sortable' error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using Angular JS and Angular UI (via a gem : angular-ui-rails) and today I'm stuck with module dependancies.
If anyone has an idea !

I would like to add the sortable module ( https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable ) on my app that looks like this example :

http://jsfiddle.net/g/hKYWr/

The thing is that I already have UI-bootstrap module loaded on it, so I try to do this :

on app.js :

```
 angular.module('ui', ['ui.bootstrap','ui.sortable']);
```

on controllers.js

```
 function dndCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
 }
```

a sortable.js [file](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/blob/master/src/sortable.js) loaded in the app.
The order of js is :

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require underscore
 //= require angular.min
 //= require ./angular/controllers/app.js
 //= require_tree ./angular
 //= require_tree .
```

and so the sortable.js file is loaded after app.js and just before ui-bootstrap js file (in ./angular tree)

Then last : my html file with a simple list loop with angular :

```
<html ....... ng-app="ui">
 .....

<div ng-controller="dndCtrl">
    <ul ui-sortable ng-model="list">
        <li ng-repeat="item in list" class="item">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr />
</div>
```

The loop's working well and UI bootstrap (Typeahead in my case too) but not sortable and console renders a

```
 TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sortable'
```

What did I do wrong or miss ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

UI-sortable depends on [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/). It doesn't look like you have included jQuery UI JavaScript file. Note that you can either include the whole jQuery UI library or create a custom build with just the sortable module.

Comment: I use jquery-ui-rails gem (version 4.0.2)

Comment: ok. My mistake ! I forgot to declare the `//= require jquery.ui.all` in application.js! It's working well ! thanks a lot to notice it :)

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. Here is the sortable demo in plunkr http://embed.plnkr.co/8s0jg3aBKDx2IIf6me83/